# Feather js disable some methods typescript

Tags: typescript, feathersjs

How can i disable some methods (get, remove) in feather js.

I using mongodb.

I want disable all methods only allow (post, patch)

Answer (score 2):

The way to enforce this is with a `before` hook.

You can use the `disallow` hook from `feathers-hooks-common` as one (good) way.

https://feathers-plus.github.io/v1/feathers-hooks-common/#disallow

```
const { disallow } = require('feathers-hooks-common');
...
app.use('myservice', ...);
const service = app.service('myservice');
service.hooks({
  // only allow create(post) and patch
  before: {
    get: disallow(),
    find: disallow(),
    remove: disallow(),
    update: disallow()
  }
});
```